# How to download a file in angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to download audio files from server.

```
import { Headers, Http, Response, RequestOptions, ResponseContentType } from '@angular/http';


downloadFile() {
    let downloadUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/enoeasy-94b34.appspot.com/o/Davido%20-%20If.mp3?alt=media&token=603f3beb-2380-42a4-a119-7bbb34769d78"
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg', 'MyApp-Application' : 'AppName', 'Accept': 'audio/*' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob });

    return this.http.post(downloadUrl, '', options)
        .map(this.extractContent)
        .catch(this.handleError);
    }

private extractContent(res: Response) {
        let blob: Blob = res.blob();
        window['saveAs'](blob, 'test.mp3');
}
```

So when the following button is clicked, I should get the test.mp3 file.
unfortunately , this is working.

```
<button md-button (click)="downloadFile()"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true" ></i> Download</button>
```

I searched online for any tutorial on downloading files with angular2, couldn't find anything that could help.

How do I go about, downloading files with angular2?

Answer (score 0):

Please Use Following way

```
downloadFile() {

    let downloadUrl = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/enoeasy-94b34.appspot.com/o/Davido%20-%20If.mp3?alt=media&token=603f3beb-2380-42a4-a119-7bbb34769d78";

var save = document.createElement('a');
            save.href = downloadUrl;
            save.target = '_blank';
            save.download = downloadUrl;
            var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            save.dispatchEvent(evt);
            (window.URL).revokeObjectURL(save.href);

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this downloads the file as a windows program which can't open or play. The file is suppose to be an mp3 file.